# Integer casting in big-endian

Tags: c++

In a big-endian machine, if I have a `long` variable and cast it to a `char`, does the language specification guarantees I will get the least significant bits after the cast?

In other words:

```
long a = 50;
char b = (char)a;
assert(b == 50); /* Is it true? */
```

I know this is true for little-endian machines, but what about big-endian?

Comment: It has nothing to do with endianness, you get the value converted to the other type, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined. (§4.7/3).

Since `char` must be able to accommodate values up to at least 127, the result in this case must be 50.

Comment: I think the OP is wondering if, that by casting the way he is, whether it grabs the "upper byte" of the long vs. the "lower byte" due to the differing endiannes.

Comment: @JimBuck Yes, that was my actual doubt, and how the standard had specified that. Since the standard talks about value and not about bytes, I assume that compilers does this it in the most obvious way, by placing the "upper byte" of the long inside the char.

Comment: @lvella: No, if anything it copies the *least* significant byte(s) into the destination. Copying the most significant bits wouldn't retain the value if it did fit.

Comment: @JerryCoffin By "upper byte" I mean the byte with greatest index in memory, which in big-endian machines correspond to the least significant bits.

Comment: @lvella: it's normally going to take the least significant bits, regardless of where they're stored.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A lot of code would otherwise break.